# Do STL algorithms functions, like accumulate, avoid copy if the function passed to them accepts a reference?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Suppose for example I want to sort a range (identified by begin and end iterators). If I pass to std::sort a lambda function whose arguments are two A& (A is a class) , then will the STL algorithm avoid copying two objects and simply call my sorting function directly ?

Comment: A code example will probably communicate your question better...

Comment: since you are not allowed to mutate either of the arguments in the predicate, specifying the arguments to be `const A&` would be ideal. In which case, no, there would be no copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) reference, we see that

> The type of dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of
>   [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) and [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible).

Thus, being copyable ([CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) or [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable)) is not in the requirements of this algorithm. This guarantees that it won't ever try to copy your objects.

Comment: cppreference.org is a great site, but it is *not* a "specification".

Comment: @NicolBolas It usually matches the standard quite nicely. Anyway, fixed the wording, thank you.